# How to get last duplicate item from a list

Tags: c#, .net, windows, linq

I have a list which contains duplicate items, and what I need is to get only the last entry of that items.

What I tried to do is below, but can't find any further solution to achieve what I need to.

```
     List<ListItem> listItems = new List<ListItem>
        {
            new ListItem{ Item1="Item1", Item2="Item2"},
            new ListItem{ Item1="Item2", Item2="Item22"},
            new ListItem{ Item1="Item3", Item2="Item23"},
            new ListItem{ Item1="Item4", Item2="Item24"},
            new ListItem{ Item1="Item4", Item2="Item244"},
            new ListItem{ Item1="Item4", Item2="Item244"},
            new ListItem{ Item1="Item5", Item2="Item25"},
            new ListItem{ Item1="Item1", Item2="Item12"},
            new ListItem{ Item1="Item6", Item2="Item26"},
            new ListItem{ Item1="Item7", Item2="Item27"},
            new ListItem{ Item1="Item1", Item2="Item22"},
            new ListItem{ Item1="Item8", Item2="Item28"},
            new ListItem{ Item1="Item9", Item2="Item29"},
            new ListItem{ Item1="Item8", Item2="Item288"},
            new ListItem{ Item1="Item10", Item2="Item210"},
            new ListItem{ Item1="Item8", Item2="Item288"},
            new ListItem{ Item1="Item11", Item2="Item211"},
        };

        listItems.GroupBy(x => x.Item1).ToList().ForEach(r =>
                {
                    //Want to get last item w.r.t. "r". because I have a complex scenario that if something does not works I also have to get second  last record, so I don't want to lose GroupBy list.
                    foreach (var item in r)
                 {
                        Console.WriteLine(item.Item1 + " " + item.Item2);
                 }
                });
```

Expected Output:

```
Item1 Item22
Item2 Item22
Item3 Item23
Item4 Item244
Item5 Item25
Item6 Item26
Item7 Item27
Item8 Item288
Item9 Item29
Item10 Item210
Item11 Item211
```

Comment: Last item ordered by what?

Comment: @zee: What is the criteria to find duplicates?  `Item1 == Item1` or `Item1 == Item1 && Item2 == Item2`? Also, if `Item1` is the same for duplicates, then ordering by `Item1` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: To make sure your question is understood, what is the expected output, given your `listItems` example above?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I updated post with expected output that I want.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that a duplicate is based on `Item`, then just get the `Last` element in a `GroupBy`.

```
var nodups = listItems
   .GroupBy(x => x.Item1)
   .Select(g => g.Last());
foreach (var item in nodups)
   Console.WriteLine(item.Item1 + " " + item.Item2);
```

Comment: I think it shoudl be g.Last().

Comment: @Nikita, oops!  You're a better compiler then me.

Comment: @RichardSchneider Thanks, but I have a different scenario. I edited my post, please refer to the comment above `foreach` loop.

Comment: Sorry can only anwer the question you post.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need for each `Item1` the last item:-

```
var result = listItems.GroupBy(x => x.Item1)
                      .Select(x => new
                            {
                               Item1 = x.Key,
                               Item2 = x.OrderByDescending(z => z.Item2).First().Item2
                            });
```

[Working Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OFYzYR)

**Update:**

I guess you need `List<ListItem>` as output type. Well for that you can use this:-

```
List<ListItem> res = listItems.GroupBy(x => x.Item1)
                              .Select(x =>
                                  {
                                       var lastItem = x.Last(); 
                                            //Or x.OrderByDescending(z => z.Item2).First()
                                       return new ListItem
                                          {
                                             Item1 = x.Key,
                                             Item2 = lastItem.Item2
                                          };
                                  }).ToList();
```

Getting following output:-

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The output is exactly what I want, but is that possible to use linq query on list "r"(refer my code), because group by is already performed there and I don't want to lose actual groupby list.

Comment: @zee - Didn't get you. Why you need the list `r`? Do you mean you need output as `List<ListItem>` ? Well that's possible but I am clueless why you need that in `r`.

Comment: as you can see that in my code, I already performed groupby on `listItems`, and inside it I am using `r` to iterate that list, so I  want to perform `linq` query on `r` to get last item.

Comment: @zee - These queries are also doing the same. What you want to do exactly? I though you want `List<ListItem>` as output so posted update accordingly.

Comment: I edited my post, please refer to the comment above `foreach` loop. Hope that clears your query.

Answer (score 1):

fiddle : https://dotnetfiddle.net/TMAcie

```
    var result = listItems
                .GroupBy(x=>new {x.Item1,x.Item2})
                .Select(g=>new {Item1 = g.Key.Item1,Item2 = g.Max(m=>m.Item2)});
```

If criteria for duplicates is with `Item1`

```
    var result = listItems
                .GroupBy(x=>x.Item1)
                .Select(g=>new {Item1 = g.Key,Item2 = g.Max(m=>m.Item2)});
```